# Discord.py - When a button is pressed it sends a message

Tags: python, discord

I have been trying to make a python discord bot that sends an embedded message with interactive buttons underneath. So far it looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to make the buttons respond though. When you click the button, it just says, "This Interaction Failed"

Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def question(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    e = discord.Embed(title="TRIVIA QUESTION", description="When did the dinosours become extinct?")
    await ctx.send(embed=e, content="", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="60 million years ago", custom_id="button1", disabled = True), Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="65 million years ago", custom_id="button2")])
```

------------------------EDIT-------------------------

Looking at the documentation commented by hYg-Cain (https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/getting-started#send-selects) I put this line in my code:

```
res = await bot.wait_for("button_click", timeout=10)
```

This waits for the user to click a button and then this:

```
if res.custom_id == "button1":
            await ctx.send("You got it right. ")
```

Means if the button pressed had an id of button1 it sent a message.

Comment: please add the related code you've written so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to write a check function to get the ID of the button clicked and then handle it via if/else stuff

```
def check_button(i: discord.Interaction, button):
        return i.author == ctx.author and i.message == msg

@bot.command()
async def question(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    e = discord.Embed(title="TRIVIA QUESTION", description="When did the dinosours become extinct?")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=e, content="", components=[Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="60 million years ago", custom_id="button1", disabled = True), Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="65 million years ago", custom_id="button2")])

   interaction, button = await client.wait_for('button_click', check=check_button)    
   if button.custom_id == "button1":
       # do stuff
   elif button.custom_id == "button2":
       # do other stuff
   else:
       # how did we get here
```

however, maybe it is easier to implement this as select option
https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/getting-started#send-selects

Comment: I got the error, `Unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: ups, accidentally copied the check_button function into the quesiton function. Updated the code, but also this is not tested, just an idea on how to tackle it

Comment: I got the error: `AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Interaction'. Did you mean: 'Integration'?`
Then I removed the `discord.` leaving `Interaction` (if this doesn't make sense sorry)
Then I got this: `AttributeError: module 'discord_components.client' has no attribute 'wait_for'`

Comment: which imports are you using?

Comment: this solution is assuming you're not using the conventional discord.py but the discord-message-components. You should have a look at the documenation I linked in my answer

Comment: I had a look at the documentation and I figured it out from there.

Comment: Maybe update your question with your corrections to help other users with simular problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ur ain't checking ur interaction.

```
interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
```

You can use it something like is

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "When did the dinosours become extinct?",
        components = [
            Button(label="60 million years ago", custom_id = "button1", disabled = True), 
            Button(label="65 million years ago", custom_id="button2")
        ]
    )

    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!")
```

Comment: Nothing changes on discord

Comment: this solution only checks if button1 was pressed and also you "disabled" button1, probably that's the problem

Comment: I copy and pasted the code in, removed the disabled bit but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Ah my bad try removing the line with button 2 and remove disable = true. That should work